# Automatically remove a row without foreign references

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am using sqlite3.
I have one "currencies" table, and two tables that reference the currencies table using a foreign key, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
     currency        TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );

CREATE TABLE table1 (
     currency        TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     FOREIGN KEY(currency) 
        REFERENCES currencies(currency)
    );

CREATE TABLE table2 (
     currency        TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     FOREIGN KEY(currency) 
        REFERENCES currencies(currency)
    );
```

I would like to make sure that rows in the "currencies" table that are not referenced by any row from "table1" and "table2" will be removed automatically. This should behave like some kind of ref-counted object. When the reference count reaches zero, the relevant row from the "currencies" table should be erased.

**What is the "SQL way" to solve this problem?**

I am willing to redesign my tables if it could lead to an elegant solution.
I prefer to avoid solutions that require extra work from the application side, or solutions that require periodic cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `AFTER DELETE TRIGGER` in each of `table1` and `table2`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_currencies_1 AFTER DELETE ON table1
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM currencies
  WHERE currency = OLD.currency
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE currency = OLD.currency);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER remove_currencies_2 AFTER DELETE ON table2
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM currencies
  WHERE currency = OLD.currency
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE currency = OLD.currency);
END;
```

Every time that you delete a row in either `table1` or `table2`, the trigger involved will check the other table if it contains the deleted `currency` and if it does not contain it, it will be deleted from `currencies`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=48b31acb83837b21821c11b42a72359e).

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way of doing this.  The reverse can be handling using cascading delete foreign key references.  The reverse is that when a currency is deleted all related rows are.

You could schedule a job daily running something like:

```
delete from currencies c
    where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.currency = c.currency) and
          not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.currency = c.currency);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need an automatic way for doing that, then most dbms provide a trigger mechanism. You can create a trigger on update and delete operations that run the folowing query:

you can use a left join for that:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

It return a row for all rows from the left table, even if there is no corresponding row in the right table, replacing the rows form the right with null. You can then check a not null right table field for null with is null. This will filter for the rows the have no counterpart in the right table.

For example:

```
SELECT currencies.currency FROM currencies LEFT JOIN table1 WHERE table1.currency IS NULL
```

will show the relevant rows for table1.
You can do the same with table two.

This will give you two queries, that shows which rows have no couterpart.
You can then use intersect on the result, so that you have the rows that have not couterpart in either:

```
SELECT * FROM query1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM query2
```

Now you have the list of currencies to be deleted.

You can finish this by using a subqueried delete:

```
DELETE FROM currencies WHERE currency IN (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: The query in the other answer would do just as well.

Comment: This kind of operation with the trigger might cost more than it's worth.